# How to resize dynamically a two dimentional vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I need to resize a two dimensional vector (of unknown size) as follows:

```
//Creating the vector of vectors: 

vector< vector< long > > v;

//Resizing the vectors:

/*Needing help here: 

my current assumption is: 
v.resize(1);
v[0].resize(1);
*/

//Adding elements:

v[0][0].push_back(0); 
v[0][1].push_back(-1);
```

The compiler is reporting error upon applying the push_back. I think i have a problem in resizing the vector.

The objective is creating a two dimensional vector that allocates memory dynamically according to the added values.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption about resizing the two dimensions is correct, but you are getting an error on push_back because the type of `v[0][0]` is `long &`, not `vector<long> &`.

I think you want:

```
 v.resize(1);
 //Don't resize the second dimension because you want it to grow dynamically
 //v[0].resize(1);
 v[0].push_back(0);
 v[0].push_back(-1);
```

Keep in mind though that push_back only resizes that particular row/column.  If you're not consistent about adding the same number of elements to `v[0]`, `v[1]`, etc, you'll end up with a "jagged" array.  You may want to wrap this whole thing up in a class to enforce that consistency.

Comment: "You may want to wrap this whole thing up in a class to enforce that consistency." Please don't do it yourself; use `boost::multi_array`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think your solution was the most accurate one in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct. But if you would like to resize all the inner vectors, then do this:

```
vector< vector< long > > v;    
v.resize(10);
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    v[i].resize(20);
```

Just remember that when you use `v` as `v[i][j]`, then make sure that `0<=i<10` and `0<=j< 20`.

---

**Now why you get error with what you're doing?**

```
v.resize(1);
v[0].resize(1); //that means, the constraint is : `0<=i<1` and `0<=j<1`

v[0][0].push_back(0); 
v[0][1].push_back(-1);  //problematic line!
```

You get error because you don't make sure that `0<=i<1` and `0<=j<1` constraints when you call `push_back` second time.

Answer (score 1):

```
// your current assumption is: 
v.resize(1);
v[0].resize(1);
// modify the value
v[0][0] = new_value;

// resize again
v.resize(2);
for ( iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter )
  iter->resize(2);
```

It is a possible and correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct, alternative to the nested containers is the Boost `multi_array`, but it is less universal.